# Error con transaccion (no transaction is in progress) en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Spring Boot y Spring Batch.

Tengo un problema al tratar de realizar un **insert** o **update** a la base de datos

```java
tsflistadosRepository.saveAndFlush(tsflistadosValidar);
```

Me da una excepción

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

He leido que debia marcar el metodo donde trato de hacer el insert con `@Transaccional` Pero no me ha funcionado asi

La configuración básica que tengo actualmente es esta

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class MailServerApplication extends DefaultBatchConfigurer implements CommandLineRunner {

    ...

}
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SpringBatchConfig {
 ...
}

@Repository
public interface TsflistadosRepository extends JpaRepository<Tsflistados,Long> {

    List<Tsflistados> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tsflistados t WHERE t.cdestado = ?1 AND t.mcnotifi = ?2 AND t.tpcomuni <> ?3 AND (t.fhiniprt < ?4 OR t.fhiniprt is null)")
    List<Tsflistados> findAllToProcess(String cdestado, String mcnotifi, String tpcomuni, Timestamp fhiniprt, Sort sort);

    Tsflistados findByNulistadoAndFhultact(Long nulistado, Timestamp fhultact);
}
```

Podrian ayudarme para ver que me faltaria agregar, gracias de antemano

Edito, agregando el metodo que falla

```java
private boolean validarListado(Tsflistados tsflistadosValidar) {
        boolean validar = false;
        Timestamp strfhFecha = DateUtils.getSystemDate(); 
        String host = "";
        try {
            host = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tsflistadosValidar.setCdestado(Constants.STATE_PROCESSED);
        tsflistadosValidar.setFhinicio(strfhFecha);
        tsflistadosValidar.setFhultact(strfhFecha);
        tsflistadosValidar.setNbserver(host);

        log.info("actualizando registro");
        tsflistadosRepository.saveAndFlush(tsflistadosValidar);
        log.info("salvo registro");
        //TODO punto 6 funcion lista validar

        //TODO RESOLVER CONEXION PARA UPDATES
        Tsflistados tsflistadosValidarAux = tsflistadosRepository.findByNulistadoAndFhultact(tsflistadosValidar.getNulistado(), tsflistadosValidar.getFhultact());
        if(tsflistadosValidar.getNbserver().equals(host)) {
            return true;
        }
        return validar;
    }
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar el bloque de codigo que da este error en especifico?

Comment: Resolvi el problema, publico la respuesta por si alguien le pasa

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver el problema, el error es debido a que el Batch usa su propio Datasource que no tiene Transaccion habilitada lo quse debia hacer era hacer que el Batch tomara el datasource de JPA en el configurator debia ser de esta forma

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SpringBatchConfig extends JpaBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    protected SpringBatchConfig(BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource, TransactionManagerCustomizers transactionManagerCustomizers, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        super(properties, dataSource, transactionManagerCustomizers, entityManagerFactory);
    }
    ....
}
```

Luego de esto el Batch si actualiza los registros correctamente